# Is there an API to configure email templates in wso2 identity server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure the email template in wso2-IS-5.1.0 through Admin web services.  Does an API exist for doing this?

Comment: Well, there is a UI provided for customizing the email templates. It's provided in the documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Email+Templates

Comment: Yes UI i have tried already.I am looking for API so that i can configure template from my application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `AccountCredentialMgtConfigService` service to get and set the email templates. The WSDL can be found at,

`https://[host]:[port]/services/AccountCredentialMgtConfigService?wsdl`

Comment: is this an admin service?

Comment: Yes. It is an admin  service